# Eregi to preg_match conversion

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

So, I have a website in which I gather data directly from another associated website, in order to display information. To do this, I am fetching the website (using file_get_contents) and stripping out anything not relevant using eregi. My problem is that even though I've done thourough research on how to convert this eregi to a not deprecated preg_match, I can not seem to find a solution.

Anyone bright enough to understand the complexities of preg_match?

Here's my current code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://www.vattenfall.se/sv/teckna-   elavtal.htm/papp/mac:24432/ma-vf_se-orderflow/ProductSelection.action?orderMode=true&submitPostalCode=&orderFlow.personal.postalCode=87140&submitPostalCode=Visa+priser");

eregi('<td style="width: 120px;" class="valuePresentation">(.*)</td>', $content, $data);

foreach($data as $split)
{
    $split = explode("</td>", $split);
}
```

This works fine - but as I said, the function is deprecated, and I would love to replace it, if only I knew how!

Comment: In preg_match() only need add delimiters in regexp pattern

Comment: Winston's comment is best.  in your case the punctuation might need to be escaped.  Try:  eregi('_<td style="width: 120px;" class="valuePresentation">(.*)</td>_', $content, $data);  Please review mario's link as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eregi('some expression', $input, $matches);
```

dark magic, chanting, spooky things...

```
preg_match('/some expression/i', $input, $matches);
```

You might want `preg_match_all()` instead, though.